# How to know which button has been clicked in a *ngFor loop?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an `ngFor` which generates multiple ion-cards. Inside each card there's a button. The problem is that when I click on any of the buttons to change its text the text of other buttons also change. How can I prevent that?

```
<ion-card  *ngFor="let item of unack, let  i = index">
<ion-card-header>
  <p [ngStyle]="{'color': buttonColor2}">{{status1}}</p>
</ion-card-header>

<ion-card-content>


   <p align="center">Stores for order</p>
  <img src="">

  <div class="orderInfo">
    <p>Delivery Time</p>
    <p>{{item.delivery_from}} to {{item.delivery_to}}</p>
  </div>

  <div class="Custom">
    <p>Customer</p>
    <p>{{item.customer_name}}  {{item.customer_surname}}</p>
  </div>


  </ion-card-content>
<ion-list>

  <button class="Ack" *ngIf="HideACk" (click)="StartS(item)">
   {{Acknowledge}}
  </button>
```

Comment: can u use stackblitz  for demonstrate please

Comment: Seems like we'd need to see `StartS()`. I don't see a problem here. You're passing the item with its scope and should be able to work with that.

Comment: The thing is when i click on the button the current text of acknowledge should change to start only for the clicked button but then what's happening is the the text of all buttons change

Comment: @jack: I'm going to take a wild guess and say you're running something equivalent to `$('.Ack').text('stuff')` which would reference all buttons. Rather, you want to use reference `e` within your `StartS` method to arrive at the individual button.

Comment: @jack please provide stackblitz code or .ts file wich include Starts() method

Comment: @Asanka: Here is the method  StartS($event,i){
    Acknowledge = "Acknowledged Order";
      this.StartO = true;
      this.HideACk = false;
  this.buttonColor2 = '#9ACD32';
  }

Comment: you are binding same Acknoledge variable to all buttons.thats why it happens

Comment: @Asanka: here is the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-lrshrg

Comment: ok what you want to do now change the colour of text when clicking on button?

Comment: you can check my answer all things are corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind all attributes to object inside the unack array. example -> every object should have Acknowledge property.

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-card  *ngFor="let item of unack, let  i = index">
    <ion-card-header>
      <p [ngStyle]="{'color': unack[i].buttonColor2}">{{unack[i].status1?unack[i].status1:""}}</p>
    </ion-card-header>

    <ion-card-content>


       <p align="center">Stores for order</p>
      <img src="">

      <div class="orderInfo">
        <p>Delivery Time</p>
        <p>{{item.delivery_from}} to {{item.delivery_to}}</p>
      </div>

      <div class="Custom">
        <p>Customer</p>
        <p>{{item.customer_name}}  {{item.customer_surname}}</p>
      </div>


      </ion-card-content>
    <ion-list>

      <button class="Ack" *ngIf="!unack[i]?.StartO" (click)="StartS($event, i)">
       Acknowledge
      </button>

      <button class="Ack" *ngIf="unack[i]?.StartO" (click)="customer_pressed($event, i)">
        Start Shopping
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

this is your edited code [Stackblits link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-rsu5mn?file=pages/home/home.ts)

Comment: Thank you so much, you've just saved my life :)

Comment: @Asnaka, you can use **item.buttonColor2**, not **unack[i]?.buttonColor2**

Comment: @Eliseo yes we can.

Answer (score 0):

It should change in all because the [interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax) that you are doing on Acknowledge variable is happening for all the cards. All cards are binding same **Acknowledge** variable, In your example, every button will consider same Acknowledge variable and value **Acknowledged Order** will be displayed. if you want you can create another property in item object, let say ack and assign some different text to it then render {{item.ack}}, check the following example

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-card *ngFor = "let item of unack">
    <button (click) = "StartS(item)" ion-button>
      {{item.ack}}
    </button></ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Js file may look like :

```
export class HomePage {
  public unack = [
    { name : 'apple', color : 'red', ack : 'Not acknowledged'},
    { name : 'orange', color : 'red', ack : 'Not acknowledged'},
    { name : 'penut', color : 'brown', ack : 'Not acknowledged'},
    { name : 'milk', color : 'white', ack : 'Not acknowledged'}
  ]
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }
  StartS(item){
    item.ack = item.ack == "Not acknowledge" ? "Acknowledged Order" : "Not acknowledge"
  }

}
```